# Background Mode not quite working, Ionic App sleeps after 5 minutes

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, background-mode

I've created an Ionic App with Capacitor that's supposed to send the GPS coordinates to an API every minute. That works generally, but when it comes to working when the screen is locked it gets troublesome.

Now, I've included cordova-background-mode, as well as ForegroundService. Yet, it still stops after 5 minutes. I've also used

```
this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
this.backgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations();
```

but to no avail.

I even manually deactivated Battery Optimisation in the settings.

What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone needs a solution, this works with android 10 + Capacitor + [native backgrounde mode](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode):

```
if (this.platform.is('android')) {

  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.backgroundMode.enable();
    this.backgroundMode.setEnabled(true);
    this.backgroundMode.on('activate').subscribe(() => {
      this.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
      this.backgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations();
    });
    this.backgroundMode.disableBatteryOptimizations();
  });

  const timer = 3 * 60 * 1000; // three minutes

  setInterval(() => {
    this.backgroundMode.wakeUp();
  }, timer);
}
```

Also add in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That plugin is broken. I had many failed attempts to make it work but failed.

The only solution I found was to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@capacitor-community/background-geolocation) one instead. It works even if the screen is locked for hours.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen an example snippet for an Ionic implementation?

Comment: there is an example in the documentation. https://github.com/capacitor-community/background-geolocation

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?